# how to a number of occurrences in a string that begin with a specific word and end with another word

Tags: c#, regex, string, split, console-application

Given I have the following information:

```
string Sentence = "The dog jumped over the cat and the cat jumped above the mouse."
string startword = "jumped"
string endword = "the"
```

My requirement is how to program in C# to count the number of occurrences that the Sentence contains the starting of the `startword` until matching the second `endword`.

The above example should return 2 because  `The dog [jumped] ... [the] cat and ...cat [jumped] .. [the] mouse.`

One of my ideas of to do string.Split the Sentence into string of words and looping through the words and compare with `startword`. If `startword` matched, then compare the next word to the `endword` until found or end of Sentence.  If the `startword` and `endword` have been found, increase the counter, and continue searching for `startword` and `endword` until end of sentence.

Any other suggestion or code sample will be appreciated.

Comment: Kindly put forward your thoughts into code.That would help .Then you could check where you are exactly struck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers here are good. However, I just thought I'd point out that you might want to respect word boundaries by using `\b`. Otherwise you might pick up partial words.

> `\b`  Matches any word boundary. Specifically, any point between a `\w` and
> a `\W`.

```
var regex = new Regex(@"\bjumped\b.*?\bthe\b");
var str = "The dog jumped over theatre cat and the cat bejumped above the mouse.";
var matches = regex.Matches(str);
Console.WriteLine("Count : " + matches.Count);
foreach (var match in matches)
{
   Console.WriteLine(match);
}
```

[**You can see the demo here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/J2Hj2R)

Comment: I think your answer to my question is the best Michael.  It is exactly what i am looking for.  Thank you so much!

Comment: @Andy if this has helped you dont forget to mark it up and mark it answered, cheers

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using regex for this.

The regex to use is pretty straightforward: `jumped.*?the`

<sup>You can play with it here: https://regex101.com/r/h0MKyV/1</sup>

Since you are expecting multiple matches, you can get them in C# using `regex.Matches` call. So your code should look like the following:

```
var regex = new Regex("jumped.*?the");
var str = "The dog jumped over the cat and the cat jumped above the mouse.";
var matches = regex.Matches(str);
```

You can iterate over the `matches` to access each match, or get their count directly.

Comment: Thank you so much.  i only need the count.  I saw other Regex examples, but i didn't know it can do wildcard search.

Answer (score 1):

```
regexPattern= "jumped[\s\w]+?the"
searchText = "The dog jumped over the cat and the cat jumped above the mouse."
```

The above regex match your question.
To count the number of occurrences use

`regexCount = Regex.Matches(searchText, regexPattern).Count`